# Trying to split string into new columns

Tags: excel, vba

In cell B2, I have a long list that starts with "ATT TAG:". I was wondering if I could divide this data into columns for every new "ATT TAG:". My data can be seen below:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I tried using functions, like InStr, and Left and right, but I thought there might be a better way to split such data up.

[1]:

Comment: Text to columns no good for you?

Comment: @Skin I just don't know how to go from arrays to columns.

Comment: Your picture only shows a part of your data, and nothing regarding what you want for a result. Since I can't paste a screenshot into Excel, I suggest you  make your data useful by editing your question to post it as text, perhaps using this [Markdown Tables Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables), or possibly upload a workbook (with sensitive information removed) to some public website and post a link in your original question.  Also, perhaps a sample of what you expect for results would be handy.  Also, show the code you have tried!

Comment: Do you want the results to be all in the same row?  or do you want the results to be in the same column?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I would like to see the results to be aligned in the same row

Comment: What about duplicate tags?

Comment: Yes, I would need each tag

Comment: I suggest a VBA macro, using Regular Expressions or VBA Split and string functions to separate the results, and a Dictionary to collect the results. You'll have to number the `Tag`'s to avoid the duplicate issue, but you can strip them off when you create the output. Somebody might do this for you, but since this is not a free codewriting service, I suggest you start with the code you have and post back with particular hurdles that you may run into, and code to illustrate how you are dealing with this.

Answer (score 0):

You've tagged your question with VBA, yet you reference formula functions in your question, so I'm not clear whether you're looking for a function, or for VBA. With that said, i'm going to roll with how you've tagged your question.

To split a string using VBA, you can use the [Split()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function) function.

Example:

```vb
Dim wordArray() As String
Dim inputString As String

inputString = "ATT TAG: HELLO, ATT TAG: WORLD, ATT TAG: ZOMBIES"
wordArray() = Split(inputString, "ATT TAG:")
```

From there, use the array to create and populate new columns however you deem appropriate.

**UPDATE:**

Assuming you have some data that looks like this; where everything is jammed into one cell, and is split by new lines:

```sh
|-----------------|---|---|---|---|
| ATT TAG: Value1 |   |   |   |   |
| ATT TAG: Value2 |   |   |   |   |
| ATT TAG: Value3 |   |   |   |   |
|-----------------|---|---|---|---|
|-----------------|---|---|---|---|
|-----------------|---|---|---|---|
```

You can iterate through the array, and then paste the result into the new column:

```vb
Sub splitTest()

    ' declare variables
    Dim wordArray() As String
    Dim inputString As String
    Dim pasteValue As String
    Dim lastColumn As Long

    ' get the input from cell A1
    inputString = Range("A1")

    ' split the input into an array
    ' using "ATT TAG:" as the delimiter
    wordArray() = Split(inputString, "ATT TAG:")

    ' loop through the array
    For Each element In wordArray

        ' find the last used column from row 1
        lastColumn = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        ' clean up the value to be pasted; remove whitespace
        ' and any newlines -- represented by "Chr(10)"
        pasteValue = Replace(Trim(element), Chr(10), "")

        ' set the last used column to the element value
        Cells(1, lastColumn + 1).Value = pasteValue

    Next element

End Sub
```

Which will produce:

```sh
|-----------------|--------|--------|--------|
| ATT TAG: Value1 |        |        |        |
| ATT TAG: Value2 | Value1 | Value2 | Value3 |
| ATT TAG: Value3 |        |        |        |
|-----------------|--------|--------|--------|
|-----------------|--------|--------|--------|
|-----------------|--------|--------|--------|
```

Comment: sorry for being unclear. I meant VBA, I'm kind new here, but I meant using VBA functions in my question. I'm still unclear on how to split an array to columns. Can you provide a little more assistance here?

Comment: That's cool, Stack Overflow can be a great resource for help. My only advice is to ensure that you take the time to provide complete context, and data, surrounding your question, so as to make it possible for those willing, to answer your question. The issue with your question in particular, and why others are downvoting it, is because you (a) shared a picture, rather than mutable data (b) did not provide enough data to surmise the true structure of that data (c) you don't clearly explain what your desired outcome is. On that note, I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why make things complicated when there is already a tool build in excel `TextToColumn` will do the job for what you want to do.

```
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=ActiveCell, DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar _
        :=";", TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

OR

```
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("B8"), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
        OtherChar:=":", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(7, 1))
End Sub
```